# Getting started with DBA

Tags: java, oracle11g

I am java professional since last one year, now I like to move with Oracle and preparing for OCA exam. I like to know the combination of oracle and Java in IT market. Being a DBA will my Java knowledge be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll do yourself a HUGE favor just by learning about database design regardless of the engine you work with. As a DBA with a development background, you'll be better able to communicate with developers because you'll understand their part of the project. Keep in mind, though, that the DBA role is much different than that of a developer, so be sure that's what you want to do.

As for the combination of Oracle and Java in the job market, you won't be disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we can't answer this question 100% correctly. It can be handy at times that you know java as a DBA. (to help the development teams you support) On the other hand: the task of a java developer and a DBA are vastly different.

It all depends on the work environment you're in.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle DBA certification exams, Java knowledge does not help you at all.

Having an understanding about database design will most likely be useful for a Java developer.

Oracle DBA certification is quite specific to certain tasks and tools from the Oracle world (that are not very useful in other areas), but you should be able to pick up some skills that are more generally applicable (such as use of SQL, basic database design issues like indexes).

Answer (score 0):

Being Oracle DBA, you can build career as development DBA too. It is best choice for you because you can understand easily requirements of developer team and their issues. There are lots roles available as Oracle DBA like production dba, uat dba, application dba, marketing dba and development dba is one those role. You can get more detail explanation from https://www.dbametrix.com/dba-role.html